# Will playing with a 12V train motor by hand damage it?

Tags: motor, trains, 12v

This question is similar to [one for PF motors](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1706).

The 12V motor bogie has considerably more resistance than does the newer PF bogie motor, which may be moved very easily when not operating.

So, if one pushes a 12V-motorized train by hand, will it cause damage to the motor?

See title "Set 7865: six wheeled Lego® train motor (12V, 1980 - 1990)" on [this page](http://horst-lehner.mausnet.de/lego/ben/9v_12v.html) for the specific motor I'm referring to.

Side note: I've noticed that the connected headlights in [the train](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/7740_Inter-City_Passenger_Train_Set) don't illuminate when pushed by hand (and have [asked a question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/what-prevents-a-12v-motor-when-pushed-by-hand-from-providing-dc-electric-out) specifically in regards to this).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the picture below the friction has to do with driving the worm wheels via regular gears while pushing the unit by hand and yes, I guess the gear teeth on the wheel axles could be damaged because of the gear ratio.

[image: Opened 12v train motor]

Comment: This looks like an early version of the 7865 motor.

Comment: How did you remove the wheel from its axle??